# How to exclude rows starting with A, B, or C in CSV with Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, csv, boolean, data-analysis

I have written the following code:

```
dataexc = data.select do |element| 
  element[:cz_name] || element[:tor_other_cz_name]
    false if [0] == “A” || [0] == “B” || [0] == “C”
    end
  end
```

This returns NameError: undefined local variable or method `“A”' for main:Object

I am trying to exclude all locations that start with A, B, or C that exist in either of two columns in my spreadsheet. I have already put the CSV file into an array in "data", and now I'm using "dataexc" to try to narrow down the criteria to exclude the rows with those locations. Can anybody please help me write this so it works?

I am also trying to figure out how to solve an encoding error (?) that is causing one of my CSVs to open with the wrong amount of values in irb. If you think you may be able to help me (any and all help is appreciated!), there is more information about what I am doing [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/14qQiULK5l6Nj9qGU9nA7oc3t87iXhfhl9cG6QxkH_1w/pub).

Update:

In case anyone else was trying to find a solution a beginner could actually understand, the current working state of the -ABC code is:

```
cleaned_data = data.reject do |e|
  letters = ["A", "B", "C"]
  if e[:cz_name]
    letters.include?(e[:cz_name][0])
  end
end

cleaned_data = cleaned_data.reject do |e|
  letters = ["A", "B", "C"]
  if e[:tor_other_cz_name]
    letters.include?(e[:tor_other_cz_name][0])
  end
end
```

Please do not post here if you are going to be condescending.

That said, if anyone else wants to help with this project, I would really appreciate it and I will credit you for it on Github.

Comment: Please format your code to help with readability.

Comment: "One more question": not how Stack Overflow works. Each question should be one unit. If you want to clarify the question, that's fine; but an unrelated question should be an unrelated Question. Also, "go back to basics" was not me being condescending, but offering the best advice I have.

Comment: OK, deleted the other question. Thank you. I thought tadman’s comment about CSI was condescending and that was what I was referring to. Your comment does presume I have something to go “back” to though, which is not true in this case; I just started learning. I have seen other beginners get very discouraged because of more experienced programmers’ snark and that sucks. Anyway thank you for your informative answer. I would like to understand your code but the last line is confusing me. Someone else told me it uses regex and that I shouldn't dive into that yet.

Comment: The last line of my answer indeed contains regex. You can replace `val =~ /^[ABC]/` with `%w(A B C).include?(val[0])`. (`%w(A B C)` is just a neater way to write `["A", "B", "C"]`.) But as it stands, it a sample of the way someone that knows Ruby well might write it.

Answer (score 5):

I'd write it thusly:

```
data.reject { |row|
  row.values_at(:cz_name, :tor_other_cz_name).any? { |val|
    val =~ /^[ABC]/
  }
}
```

"reject the rows where any of the values in columns `:cz_name` and `:tor_other_cz_name` matches the pattern 'starts with A, B or C'."

As to your code, many errors there.

- `def` defines a method, not a variable. If you were trying to define a method, don't use `=`.
- `for` is hardly ever used in Ruby, and you can't use it with this syntax
- `element[:cz_name] || element[:tor_other_cz_name]` will just be `element[:cz_name]` if it's present, or the other one if it is not. It will not check both.
- `[0]` is not the first character of a string, it is an array with a zero inside. `element[:cz_name][0]` would be the first character of that string.
- `if condition; bool = true; else; bool = false; end` is equivalent to `bool = condition`
- `“A”` is not the same as `"A"`. Don't write your code in Word or any other word processor, use a text editor: smart quotes are a death in programming.
- if your last value is `false if condition`, in case of `condition` being true the return value will be `nil`. Both `nil` and `false` are falsey, so you end up not discriminating anything.

I suggest relearning Ruby grammar. Find a book or a tutorial somewhere, and do all exercises, in order. You have way too many basic errors.

Comment: Absolutely! A book or reference is absolutely essential to understanding the grammar. This question is so full of confusion it's obvious something to explain the rules is necessary. This isn't CSI. You can't just type in random code and expect it to work.